# mysql create database and user from non root user

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a non root user in mysql database. It has grant, create, create user permissions. I need to create a new database and user using that account. Then i need to grant basic usage permissions to newly created user on the newly created database..

I was able to create a new database and user using the non root user. Now when it comes to granting permission for newly created user on newly created database using the non root user i get permission denied for non-root user on newly created user... Any workaround?

---

Included from OP's comments:

**Executing**:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'non_root_account_name'@'his_host'
```

**Resulted the following**:

```
 GRANT CREATE, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE USER 
    ON *.* 
    TO 'non_root_account_name'@'localhost' 
       IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password' 
       WITH GRANT OPTION  
 GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, 
       DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, SHOW VIEW 
    ON non_root_account_name.* 
    TO 'non_root_account_name'@'localhost' 
       WITH GRANT OPTION`  
 GRANT SELECT 
    ON mysql`.* 
    TO 'non_root_account_name'@'localhost'`
```

Comment: Did you execute FLUSH PRIVILEGES?

Comment: Hi Pablo,
Nope. I am actually executing the queries with php. So, i would be logging in to mysql through the non root user. So, when should flush be executed?

Comment: Just after you changed some privilege. Open the MySQL console as root and execute FLUSH PRIVILEGES

Comment: Um.... The thing is that i am doing all the setup using php script.. So, i need everything to be done over the connection established from my script...

Comment: If you restart your mysql service you will get the same result

Comment: A tried flush after and sadly it doesn't seem to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation on [***GRANT*** privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) :

> *To use GRANT, you must have the GRANT OPTION privilege, and you must have the privileges that you are granting.*

Meaning, your account to grant privileges to other users, it should have a `GRANT OPTION` privilege.

Connect as `root` and re-execute `grant` on your account to grant the above privilege.

**Example**:

```
GRANT
  -- list of privileges here
  -- to your account name @ host
  WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: Hi,
I am actually executing the queries with php. So, i would be logging in to mysql through the non root user. I have double check and the account has grant privilege

Comment: You mean the non root user has `grant option` privilege?

Comment: Can you please add results of the statement `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'non_root_account_name'@'his_host';`

Comment: Sure.. This is the output 



`GRANT CREATE, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE USER ON *.* TO     'non_root_account_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'   WITH GRANT OPTION`
    `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER,   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, SHOW VIEW ON `non_root_account_name`.* TO   'non_root_account_name'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`
    `GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.* TO 'non_root_account_name'@'localhost'`